How to make AWS lambda function change IP address after each invocation?
I have a lambda function that scrapes a website, and I wish to start using it in a "massive" way (about 250 times in an 8 minute window once a day). The idea is taking a "fire and forget" approach that invokes the lambda 30 times every minute or so
My concern is that probably those 30 lambda invocations will try to access the website with the same IP address and become blocked...
Following this question I could make the lambda redeploy after each invocation, but since I will be having 30 at the same time, that would probably raise problems
If I invoke the same lambda function 30 times at the same time, will those 30 executions share the same IP address?

Why don't you work with the site's terms and conditions instead of against them?

We do not encourage people to violate a website's Terms & Conditions. If the site wants people to be able to retrieve information from the site, they will provide an API. Check whether they have a Developer portal with API documentation.

As other suggested you should not violate the website terms of use and you might get at this data via an API or something but you can play nicely by perhaps doing something like this:
Event -> Lambda disbatcher -> sqs region 1 -> Lambda scraper 1 -> S3
                           -> sqs region 2 -> Lambda scraper 2 -> S3
                           -> sqs region 3 -> Lambda scraper 3 -> S3

Where the disbatcher can add delays to each message so you do not violate/slam the web server. For example your 250 message could be spread accross 10 regions with 25 lambda invocations with a 10 second delay on first message followed by 20s delay on the second, 30s on the third and so on.
Also question if you really need this data in 8 minutes flat, seems arbitrary. If you really need it that fast I would contact the producer and work something out -- you never know could result in a win win scenario.
PS: The rule on this are murky, for example X/Twitter just lost a case against a scraper. If this data is public and you are not running afoul of copyright law or similar then it is fair game. Just follow the Law and when that is gray then follow Wheaton's law
